# Как обновить значение в словаре который записан в список?

Tags: c#, list, словари, value

есть вот такая схема из списков словарей.
Сделано это для удобства хранения в одном файле.

```c#
        class PluginData
        {
            public Dictionary<string, string> Deploys = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            public Dictionary<string, int> Destroys = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }
        
        public string chatName = "Ивент RB";
        PluginData pluginData;

        void Loaded()
        {
            LoadPluginData();
        }

        void LoadPluginData()
        {
            pluginData = Interface.GetMod().DataFileSystem.ReadObject<PluginData>("RBEvent");
        }

        void SavePluginData()
        {
            Interface.GetMod().DataFileSystem.WriteObject("RBEvent", pluginData);
        }
```

Далее в скрипте мне нужно обновить одно из заранее записанных значений в словаре `Destroys` я пытаюсь обратится к нему как `++pluginData.RBDestroys.Destroys.destroyer;` (по сути значение является числом) мне нужно просто добавить к нему единицу, каждый раз когда выполняются условия и сохранить обратно в файл `SavePluginData()` но мой древний компилятор ругается:  `` error CS1061: Type `System.Collections.Generic.List<Oxide.Plugins.RBEvent.RBDestroys>' does not contain a definition for `destroyer' and no extension method `destroyer' of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<Oxide.Plugins.RBEvent.RBDestroys>' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? ``
Что ему не подходит? что я не так делаю?
Тут выполняю код:

```c#
        void OnKilled(TakeDamage damage, DamageEvent evt)
        {
            if(evt.victim.idMain == null || evt.attacker.idMain == null) return;
            if(damage != null && evt.victim.idMain is DeployableObject && evt.victim.idMain.name == "RepairBench(Clone)")
            {
                var attacker = evt.attacker.client.netUser;// Уничтожил
                var attacked = evt.victim.client.netUser;// Уничтоженный
                var destroyer = evt.attacker.client.netUser.displayName;
                var structure = evt.victim.idMain as DeployableObject;
                Puts(destroyer+" уничтожил "+structure.name+" игрока "+attacked.displayName);
                
                //Проверка что уничтожен не свой RB
                
                //structure != null && attacker != null
                // && !attacker.admin
                // && evt.damageTypes == DamageTypeFlags.damage_explosion)
                foreach (var x in pluginData.Destroys)
                {
                    if (!pluginData.Destroys.ContainsKey(destroyer)) {
                        pluginData.Destroys.Add(destroyer, 0);
                    } else {
                        //int kills = pluginData.Destroys.Value();
                        ++pluginData.Destroys[destroyer];
                        //pluginData.RBDestroys.Add(RBDeploys { Destroys = Dictionary<string, int> {{destroyer, kills+1}} });
                        //pluginData.Destroys[destroyer] = pluginData.Destroys[destroyer]+1);
                        SavePluginData();

                        rust.SendChatMessage(attacker, chatName, "Вы только что уничтожили Repair Bench! Всего уничтожил: "+pluginData.Destroys[destroyer]);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `pluginData` - это `class PluginData`, ок, в нем мы смотрим `RBDestroys` - находим `List<RBDestroys> RBDestroys` и вот далее у вас что-то странное, как вы пытаетесь взять из коллекции `.Destroys`, какой? Это коллекция и их там много, нужен как минимум индекс (`pluginData.RBDestroys[0].Destroys`). Ну хорошо, допустим взяли, дальше смотрим `Destroys` - находим `Dictionary<string, int> Destroys` и тут опять фиг пойми что, это словарь, где есть куча объектов, а вы пытаетесь напрямую взять `.destroyer`, как вы это себе представляете? Тут опять нужен ключ (`pluginData.RBDestroys[0].Destroys["key"]`)

Comment: destroyer это заранее обозначенная переменная которая может присутствовать в ключах, перед этим идет проверка есть ли такой ключ и если есть то я уже с ним работаю. а вот на счет индекса спасибо, буду пробовать, так как при этом выполняю foreach где x ищет в pluginData.RBDestroys

Comment: что то не выходит: теперь выдает такое: ```error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `Oxide.Plugins.RBEvent.RBDestroys' expression to type `int'``` в вопрос добавил часть кода в которой работаю.

Comment: `destroyer это заранее обозначенная переменная` - без разницы что это. Обращение к значению словаря идет по ключу через индексатор `словарь["Ключ"]` и не как иначе. Следуйте подсказкам студии, а не слепо пишите/копируйте код! Вот давайте на чистоту, вы это сами писали? Ибо столько ошибок... Как? Допустим `pluginData.RBDestroys.Destroys.Value`, какое `Value` у словаря? `RBDestroys[x]` в коллекции `RBDestroys` есть элемент под номером `x`? `x` является числом? Почему вы пишете `$"..."`, но затем делаете `+kills`? Зачем вам `foreach`, если вы его не используете по назначению?

Comment: Ну и самый важный вопрос, зачем вам коллекция классов, которые содержать словари? Это бессмысленно, почему просто не использовать коллекцию словарей, без всякий `RBDestroys`?

Comment: все это я скопировал из различных скриптов в один и немного под себя подогнал
и вы удивитесь, но я работаю без студии! пишу в блокноте, компилирую и отлаживаю на сервере древним компилятором!)

Comment: x это индекс текущего элемента с которым работает foreach или я ошибаюсь?
Ну у словаря есть Key и Value или Name?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Для справки: все вопросы от этого участника - плагины к серверу Oxide Legacy, где компилятор примерно C# уровня .NET 3.5 только понимает. Плюс система плагинов блокирует подключение любых кастомных неймспейсов и запрещает использовать многопоточность. Почему автор не стал настраивать для написания плагинов Visual Studio - уже другой вопрос, на который у меня нет ответа.

Comment: @aepot Но это не отменяет тот факт, что тут нарушен синтаксис C#.

Comment: @karakym `x это индекс текущего элемента` - если вам нужен индекс, то используйте `for`, сам `foreach` перебирает элементы в коллекции и в `x` у вас будет сам объект этой коллекции. `Ну у словаря есть Key и Value или Name` - вопрос тот же, какой из `Value` вы хотите взять? Их там много, ибо словарь - разновидность коллекций.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ получается я могу использовать `pluginData.RBDestroys.x` внутри `foreach` ? `Value` в моем случае есть ключ и его значение, ключ `key` значение `value` или это не так? По поводу `$"..."` даже и не знаю зачем нужен знак доллара перед строкой, но как я понял при этом нельзя добавлять переменные (хоть компилятор на это и не жаловался)

Comment: `foreach (тип переменная in коллекция) { переменная.нужные_с_ней_операции; }` тип переменной зависит от того, какой тип у вас в коллекции, если допустим у вас `List<string> коллекция;`, то в цикле типом будет `string`, ибо коллекция строк. Если `List<НекийКласс>`, то типом в `foreach` будет этот `НекийКласс`. У вас идет перебор `RBDestroys`, который у вас `List<RBDestroys>`, то есть `x` в вашем случае, это `RBDestroys` класс. `$"..."` - это [Интерполяция строк](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.5.php), которая позволяет делать `string val = $"Привет {name}"`, где `name` это некая переменная

Comment: Словарь... Вы читали хоть базовую документацию? Хорошо, переходим на детский уровень. У вас есть корзинка цветов, вам надо определить цвет каждого цветка, как вы будете это делать? Наверно будете по очереди смотреть/брать каждый цветок и определять его цвет, так? Также и тут. у вас есть коллекция неких объектов, их там много, вы пишете `Коллекция.Значение`, у какого вы объекта пытаетесь взять значение? Их несколько. То есть у вас неверная операция. Что бы она была верная, вам надо взять сам объект и уже у него брать значение. Делается это при помощи ключа или индекса или цикла.

Comment: К примеру, `Коллекция[0].Значение` - вы берете значение первого объекта в коллекции. В случае со словарем, это будет `Словать[ключ].Значение` - вы возьмете объект, который соответствует ключу и берете его значение. Или `foreach(var объект in Словать) { объект.Значение }` - вы перебираете весь словарь и у каждого объекта достаете его значение. Так что скажите мне теперь, правильно-ли то, что вы написали `pluginData.RBDestroys.x`? И установите студию!!! Она вам в сотню раз жизнь облегчит.

Comment: Я переосмыслил все что делал исходя из ваших советов, поправок и рекомендаций, выше обновил код, на актуальный!
Для студии, нужно где то взять эти reference (если я не ошибаюсь) которые потом вставляются как using ... у меня нет верных исходников того с чем я работаю, оно шифровано не сервере (на верхнем уровне ftp каталога к которому доступа нет)

Comment: Как видите теперь я обращаюсь `var x in pluginData.Destroys`, но тут я чет "завис" или башка сломалась, не могу понять что в данном случае принимает `x` ? Это `Destroys` то есть `ключ:значение` ? Как тогда правильно составить условие проверки этого ключа? Получается я могу написать так: `if(x.ContainsKey(destroyer))` то есть перебираем весь словарь и если найдено совпадение ключа с `destroyer` то выполняем действия. Пока что у меня никак не выходит((

Comment: А зачем вам перебор, если вы можете сразу брать нужное значение по ключу? `X` в вашем случае это некий `KeyValuePair`, объект, который содержит ключ и значение и вы можете их достать так `x.Key` - ключ, и `x.Value` - значение. Но вопрос тот-же, зачем вам перебор, если нужен конкретный? Берите сразу `pluginData.Destroys["ключ"]` или делайте вашу проверку `pluginData.Destroys.ContainsKey(...)`. По поводу студии - эти библиотеки должны быть в игре, подключите их к проекту и студия вам будет подсказывать, найти только нужно верную `.dll`. Они не могут быть на сервере.

Comment: Я попробовал так... `foreach(var x in pluginData.Destroys.Keys){if(pluginData.Destroys[x].ContainsKey(destroyer)){` ...так стоп! Вы говорите что можно не перебирать? То есть я просто проверяю `if(pluginData.Destroys.ContainsKey(destroyer))` и выполняю действие? А он уже сам сгоняет глянет не завалялся ли где ни будь в длинном списке ключ с таким же значением как и у `destroyer`? Мне нужно проверить так: Сначала я проверяю на отсутствие и если отсутствует то создаю ему запись со значением 0 и потом уже делаю его +1, а если он присутствует то просто делаю +1
А вот я и не знаю какой из `dll`

Comment: Если ваша логика подразумевает лишь работу с одним ключом, то да, вам перебор циклом тут не нужен. Вы можете смело делать нечто [такое](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MXZarX). Выше я вам лишь говорил, что если вы используете цикл, то в X у вас тот объект, что в коллекции. `А вот я и не знаю какой из dll` - попробуйте их открыть например через ILSpy и найти там используемые методы, ну либо на бум подключайте каждую по очереди в проект и смотрите что в ней есть.

Comment: в любом случае спасибо, вы мне очень помогли!
сейчас то что я запланировал уже на 60% готово и работает как часики.
у меня нет сомнений, что тот код который у меня сейчас в распоряжении еще может быть оптимизирован, упрощен и почищен. Но я буду еще с ним работать, обновлять, чего то нового узнавать. Спасибо!